# How to set React function component prop to span JSX element type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I currently use `StyledComponent<"span", any, any, never>`, but would like to drop the [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) dependency.

```js
import React from "react"
import { StyledComponent } from "styled-components"

interface OptimizedImageProps {
  shadowWrapper?: StyledComponent<"span", any, any, never>
}
```

I want to make sure `shadowWrapper` returns a `span`.

Comment: I was thinking of using the type `ReactElement<HTMLSpanElement>`, but for some reason, it doesn't force the element to be a span :/